# Java: Base58-encode String

Tags: address, multi-signature, java, base58

I would like to Base58-encode this String:

```
    56379c7bcd6b41188854e74169f844e8676cf8b8
```

My current Java code looks like this:

```
    String test9 = "56379c7bcd6b41188854e74169f844e8676cf8b8";
    byte[] b2 = new BigInteger(test9,16).toByteArray();
    String test8 = Base58.encode(b2);
    System.out.println(test8);
```

As result I get:

```
    2CffxtJsCdzJEaHXHjSkvb12p12P
```

but I should get:

```
    39YteymR86cG7V3Kijg8Gm2ST1r4nTeM1b
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: @Ryan_McGeary What is the library that you got access to Base58 class? I like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is correct given the input that you used.

However, If you are expecting to get an output address of `39YteymR86cG7V3Kijg8Gm2ST1r4nTeM1b`, it looks like your input is incorrect. It's missing the first byte and the last 4 bytes (encoded as hex):

```
  Your Input: --56379c7bcd6b41188854e74169f844e8676cf8b8--------
Proper Input: 0556379c7bcd6b41188854e74169f844e8676cf8b86e1b34ba
```

---

### [Try this tool for validating your expectations](http://lenschulwitz.com/base58):

[image: Example Form]

Comment: Thanks! From where did you know I need do add 05 and 6e1b34ba?

Comment: I dont know the address before. I only know the String which has then to be base58-encoded to show me the address.

Comment: @A.c From the site that I linked to in my answer. I reversed your expected output.